# Delayed Layout of Buttons (Swift 3)

Tags: swift, autolayout, swift3

I have a ViewController with a few buttons and it also has a child view that has a sublayer added to it. Its size is equal to the size of the ViewController's main view.

I used `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` on `viewDidLoad()` and also dispatched the sublayer to the main dispatch with `DispatchQueue.main.async{...}`.  While the sublayer gets drawn immediately, the buttons take anywhere from 10-15 seconds to appear.

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I used `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` on `viewDidLoad()`

Well, don't. The view is not even in the interface yet. Layout will take place at the proper time; don't cause trouble by trying to shortcircuit things.

> and also dispatched the sublayer to the main dispatch with DispatchQueue.main.async{...}. While the sublayer gets drawn immediately, the buttons take anywhere from 10-15 seconds to appear.

Despite what you say about the main thread, this sort of delay is always due to a threading issue: you are trying to talk to the interface off the main thread, or doing some sort of synchronous networking. You have shown no code, so no more can be said, but a threading issue is certainly the cause.

Comment: thank you for pointing me in the right direction so far. After cleaning this semi-mess up, I'll post some code in a bit.